# How to recall history in teminal

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 yesterday. Then while using the terminal I noticed that once I quit a terminal session its history is gone, although history exists for applications in terminal like-ROOT(CERN) history.

In giving the command

```
echo $HISTFILESIZE
```

it shows 2000. I changed that to 10000 when I quit the session and opened a new terminal; it again shows history as 2000 and no command can be accessed through up/down arrow key.

Please help. I am getting frustrated with soooo....  lot of typing in the terrminal.

Comment: What is the output if you type `history` in terminal?

Answer (score 8):

If no commands can be run using <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> that indicates that your history file is empty or you have no read-permissions. Check that.

Maybe you run the commands as another user. If so do:

```
su otheruser
history 10
```

and look at the output.

If you change `$HISTFILESIZE` the changes will be overwritten, whenever you invoke an other shell. To prevent that you should change that variable in your `.bashrc`. Also you should set the variable `$HISTSIZE`  to a larger value.

**Generally usefull tips using histories:**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does a reverse search of your history for you. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> pastes the last argument of the last command into your prompt at cursor position.

Also the bang (`!`) operator will repeat commands for you in terminal (if it's just about saving you some typing. Example:

```
confus@confusion:~$ echo "bang + letters will repeat the last command starting with these letters."
bang + letters will repeat the last command starting with these letters.

confus@confusion:~$ clear

confus@confusion:~$ !ech
bang + letters will repeat the last command starting with these letters.
```

All those histroy related things are stored in the home directory of any user in a file called `.bash_history`. You can look them up by using the `history`-command. Her is a small tutorial on [howto use history](http://www.basicconfig.com/linux/linux_bash_history).

```
confus@confus:~$ history 4 #will print last 4 commands
 1848  ls
 1849  clear
 1850  vi /home/confus/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
 1851  history 4
```

Another very usefull thing is to create a `.inputrc` file in your home directory with the following content:

```
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

This way you can use the <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> to complete commands you started to type from history. E.g. when you type a rather lenghty command such as `rsync -a -v --human-readable --prune-empty-dirs -e 'ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa' --include="*/" --exclude="snapshot_*" --exclude="restart.*" /scratch/ x@cluster1:/home/x/runs/` and want to run it a second time you can just type `rsy` and then <kbd>↑</kbd> an it will complete to the last command that started with rsy. Another press of the uparrow will complete to the second-last and so on. I don't know why this isn't the default.

Comment: thaks a lot bro.

Comment: Alt + R? Ctrl + R in my bash.

Comment: @SUMIT you're welcome. if that answered it, set the ceckmark left of the answer... @Lekensteyn corrected. did too much copy&paste ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and search through your bash history if you remember a part of the command you entered.

There is also a file called `.bash_history` in your home folder that you can open or grep to find your previously entered commands.